# QML using Repeater and Delegate, old list is shown

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am using Repeater and Delegate to display a list, it all works fine but when i clean the model the GUI does not clean it, still old list is shown. I pass the model from cpp connector to qml.
I have tried update(), repaint() but no avail.
Any leads would be helpful.

Cpp code:

```
void ModelCpp::clearMessage() {
    qDeleteAll(messageList);
    messageList.clear();
    emit messageListUpdated();
}
```

QML

````
ColumnLayout {

                spacing: 1
                Repeater{
                    model: modelCpp.messageList
                    delegate: Rectangle {
                                  visible: true
                                  color: colorBoxShader
                                  Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                                  Layout.preferredHeight: 20

                                  RowLayout{
                                      anchors.fill: parent

                                      Text {
                                          text: modelData.label
                                          Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
                                          Layout.leftMargin: layoutLeftMargin
                                          color: "white"
                                          font.bold: true

                                      ...


    ```
````

Edit:

I narrowed down to QStackedWidget, I am using QStackedWidget to load different pages. It was clear on one screen but now I noticed it is happening on all screen. Until the qml page is not current page, it is not updated and has old value. How can I rerender page in background when it is not current page.

Comment: Is `messageListUpdated` declared as the `NOTIFY` signal for the `messageList` property?

Comment: yes @JarMan
`Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> messageList READ getMessageList NOTIFY messageListChanged)`

Comment: So your `NOTIFY` is `messageListChanged`, but your `clearMessage` function emits `messageListUpdated`. Is that a typo?

Comment: ah no, typo here. `Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> messageList READ getMessageList NOTIFY messageListUpdated)`

Comment: If you're not emitting `messageListChanged`, then the QML will not know that the model has changed.

Comment: I figured out the issue With QStackedWidget only the visible page is updated/repainted but not the invisible page. When the invisible page becomes visible it is painted. Create new QQuickWidget each time and add it to QStackedWidget.

Comment: Please ignore `messageListChanged` it is typo here. I am emitting correct signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. With QStackedWidget only the visible page is updated/repainted but not the invisible page. When the invisible page becomes visible it is painted and you will see old values briefly before new values are painted. Create new QQuickWidget each time and add it to QStackedWidget.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Plus your question used QML code, not widgets. Are you really mixing widgets with QML?

Comment: No, QQuickWidget to display QML and QStackedWidget to stack different QML pages.